# Possible to search case-sensitive?

Tags: search, attachments

We have a list with resumes attached, about 50/50 between .doc and .docx. The resumes list projects by category, e.g. Highways, Bridges, Airports, etc.

I would like to search to see whom and how many resumes have a particular category. Currently any search for "AIRPORTS" returns any instance of that word and not only when it is used as a category. The only ways I can think to do this are to either require the search to be case sensitive (categories are bold and all caps) or search by category and restrict to the text style used in the Word document (categories have their own named text style).

Are either of these things possible?
Can anyone think of an alternative?

Comment: Have you tried putting either of these into the search bar? Category:Airports or Category:Airports <search term>

Comment: No. "category" isn't defined anywhere in SharePoint. "Categories" are just headings in the Word documents with a particular style. Can SP search only in specified document styles?  ETA: Though searching Category:Airports is giving me curious results.

Comment: I assumed category was a column  you had on the list/library that you were tagging the files with.

Comment: unfortunately no. they are not in a library, they are attachments to a list. Ended up downloading Grep and searching the underlying file structure.